# Restore scroll position on page refresh (F5) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, page-refresh, scroll-position

when I refresh a view on my website I would like it to take the user to the same position on the page, right now every time I refresh it takes the user back to the top.

It should always go to the top when you switch between different pages but for refresh/F5 on the same view it should not take you back to the top.

I tried  a few other solutions to this problem on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.